# Typescript ES5 helper methods duplicated

Tags: typescript, webpack, ecmascript-next

I'm using typescript and webpack to compile my ES+ code down to ES5, with each module contained in its own output bundle.

For example:

```
class User {} = 1.js
class Table {} = 2.js
```

When looking at the output I'm noticing duplicate functions across the bundles, e.g:

```
__decorate
__awaiter
__generator
```

These are obviously helpers from the transpile down to ES5, is there any way to move these into a shared bundle to reduce duplication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is achieved with [`importHelpers` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). It imports all helper functions in every place they are needed.

It requires to install `tslib` package.